# Pointwise convergence of Fourier-Legendre Series expansion

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces, legendre-polynomials

Recall the **Fourier-Legendre expansion** of any given function $f$ of $L^2(-1,1)$:

> $$\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N}\left[(2n+1)\int_{-1}^{1}f(s)P_n(s)ds\right]P_n\underset{N\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}f$$

Where $P_n$ denotes the **Legendre Polynomials**, and "$\underset{N\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}$" means convergence in $L^2(-1,1)$, i.e the $||\cdot||_2$ norm of the difference converges towards $0$.

Now, convergence in $L^2(-1,1)$ doens't imply pointwise convergence, but I have found the following result:

> $$\text{If }\sum\left((2n+1)\int_{-1}^{1}f(s)P_n(s)ds\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\text{ converges absolutely,}$$
>
> $$\text{then the aforementioned Fourier-Legendre expansion of }f\text{ converges pointwise towards }f.$$

The thing is, after some numerical tests it looks to me that there exists absolutely no function $f$ that checks this condition: the series always seems not only to not converge absolutely, but even to diverge dramaticaly.

Would someone be able to provide me with an example of a function $f$ that respects this condition?

Comment: Try with $|t| < 1$ and $f_t(x) = \frac{1}{1-2xt+t^2} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty P_n(x) t^n$. Let $p_n = \frac{P_n}{\|P_n\|_2}=  \sqrt{n+1/2}P_n$, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Asymptotes) it is indicated that $0<\lim \sup p_n(x) \le C(x)$ thus $\sum_n \langle f,p_n\rangle p_n$ converges pointwise and locally uniformly to $f$ whenever $\sum_n | \langle f,p_n\rangle| < \infty$.

Comment: @HarmonicSun Where did you find this result ?